# PHP Related items from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been googling for a while and searching SO but I still can't find an answer.

So my problem is that I want to pull related content from mySQL database on what id is currently being displayed on the page. In the database I have a column dedicated to keywords, and I am using the LIKE query to pull id's based on those keywords. However, I get only one id because the LIKE query looks at the keyword literally. For example, keyword1 = 'apples berries oranges' is not the same as keywords2 = 'apples' 'berries' 'oranges'. I want the latter so it can pull in more related data.

I also think I may be approaching this wrong, but I don't know any other way to pull related items.

Here's my code...

```
<?php
            include 'data/data_connect.php';

            if ($sugg_qs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE keywords LIKE '$keywords' LIMIT 4")) {
                if ($q_count = $sugg_qs->num_rows) {
                    echo $q_count;
                        while($row = $sugg_qs->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo $row->title;
                        }
                            $sugg_qs->free();
                        } else {
                            die('error');
                        }
                } else {
                    die('error');
            }
        ?>
```

---

UPDATE

```
if ($sugg_qs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', '$keywords' ,'%') LIMIT 3")) {
                if ($q_count = $sugg_qs->num_rows) {
                    $row = $sugg_qs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($row as $rows) {
                        echo $rows['title'];
                    }
                } else {
                    die('error');
            }
```

This code does work with id's that only have one keyword. So I guess a possible (but undesired) solution would be to create a new column for each new keyword and use LIKE for each keyword.

Is there a way to avoid creating more columns?

THANKS for those who helped already :)

---

FINAL UPDATE?
Ok. So I figured it out in probably the messiest way to write code, but apparently it works for me. So first of all I standardized my table where each element is limited to only 5 keywords and 1 category. So in the query I call for items with similar keywords, and if there aren't similar results I then call for items from the same category from the original item.

Here is the (messy) code for those looking for a solution!

```
$q_kw_arr = explode(' ', $keywords);

            if ($sugg_qs = $db->query("SELECT keywords, category, title FROM questions WHERE keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', '$q_kw_arr[0]' ,'%') OR CONCAT('%', '$q_kw_arr[1]' ,'%') OR CONCAT('%', '$q_kw_arr[2]' ,'%') OR CONCAT('%', '$q_kw_arr[3]' ,'%') OR CONCAT('%', '$q_kw_arr[4]' ,'%') OR category= '$category' LIMIT 4")) {
                if ($q_count = $sugg_qs->num_rows) {
                    $row = $sugg_qs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($row as $rows) {
                        echo $rows['title'];
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'error';
                    }
            }
```

SPECIAL THANKS TO..

Terminus, Grzegorz J, and infidelsawyer

Comment: Did you try to use %keyword% ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I still only get one item.

Comment: So if `$keywords` is `apples berries oranges` you want to return any `questions` where `keywords` contains `apples`, `berries` or `oranges`?

Comment: Yes, I want to relate keywords of one question to keywords of another question. The code I found out works for questions that have only one keyword, but not multiple. So I'm assuming creating a new column for each keyword is a solution but it seems messy.

Comment: You should normalize your data structure for storing keywords – then this would be relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

You might need some checking if there are any keywords in the `$keywords` variable but here is a solution that works with your current structure.

Presuming each keyword in the string is separated by a space:

```
$keywordSeparator = " ";
$keywords = explode($keywordSeparator, $keywords);
$keywordsWhere = " WHERE keywords LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR keywords LIKE '%", $keywords) . "%'";

$query = "SELECT *
FROM questions 
" . $keywordsWhere;

if ($sugg_qs = $db->query($query)) {
```

**Edit**

Paul Spiegel made some good comments (not just pointing out the error in my code:)

If you want to avoid partial matches on keywords then you should wrap all keywords in a separator.

So to avoid `apple` matching `appliepie` you would store the keyword with spaces around the keyword. So `apple oranges` becomes `apple oranges`. A search for those keywords would be `WHERE keywords LIKE '% apple %' OR keywords LIKE '% oranges %'`.

However, at that point, you should see performance improvements if you store the keywords in there own table, one keyword per row. A sample table structure for a modified `questions` table and the new `question_keywords` table below:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `questions`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
`question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `question_keywords`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question_keywords` (
`keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyword_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
--
-- Indexes for table `question_keywords`
--
ALTER TABLE `question_keywords`
 ADD KEY `question_id_keyword` (`question_id`,`keyword`);
```

Some sample data

```
INSERT INTO `questions` (`title`) VALUES ('Question #1'), ('Question #2'), ('Question #3');

INSERT INTO `question_keywords` (`question_id`, `keyword`)
VALUES
    (1, 'apple')
    ,(2, 'orange')
    ,(3, 'ILikeFruit')
    ,(3, 'banana')
    ,(3, 'grape')
    ,(3, 'apple');
```

You can then search like this

```
$keywordSeparator = " ";
$keywords = explode($keywordSeparator, $keywords);
$keywordsAnd = "'" . implode("','", $keywords) . "'";

$query = "
  SELECT DISTINCT q.*
  FROM questions q
  INNER JOIN question_keywords k
    ON q.question_id = k.question_id
    AND k.keyword IN (" . $keywordsAnd . ")";

if ($sugg_qs = $db->query($query)) {
```

The search might seem more complicated since we now need that `JOIN` but it should speed up since it doesn't have to search using `%` and can take advantage of the index we have of the `keyword` column.

Comment: I copied your code and put an else statement at the end of it to echo error, and I received 'error'. I'm assuming something is wrong with the query. I'm trying to mess with it right now...

Comment: Could be the query finds no results as your code prints `error` if the count is 0. If you edit your question to include the table structure with a few sample rows, I can help a lot more.

Comment: You forgot the quotes: `$keywordsWhere = " WHERE keywords LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR keywords LIKE '%", $keywords) . "%'";`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I did indeed. Thanks.

Comment: I would also put the separator around the keywords to avoid partial matching. `'question answer' LIKE '%quest%'` is TRUE but `' question answer ' LIKE '% quest %'` is FALSE.

Comment: that would be work really well if that's how the keywords are stored in the column. Imagine if he didn't have a first and last space. I guess it depends on what he wants. If he likes the idea of spaces around his keywords then, he should have another table that stores the keywords, 1 per row. That would allow searches to be performed without `%` . It all depends on if OP likes the partial matching or not. @AlexManzano? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if ($sugg_qs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE keywords LIKE CONCAT('%', $keywords ,'%') LIMIT 4")) {
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting only one item. If your code does work, then I must have something wrong in my while loop.

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused about your if-else structure, but it appears that you're attempting to use an else with a while statement (which I don't believe PHP supports). You would need to remove the else statement directly under the while loop or you would need to add an if statement before $sugg_qs->free();. I'm not sure that would explain your findings, but I wanted to point this out.

Comment: The loop works because I tried a different id, and it pulled in all the related id with the LIMIT 4, but that's because that specific id only had one keyword. My other ids have multiple keywords. So I guess I have to make a column for each keyword for this to work. But thanks for your input :)

Comment: If you have always keywords in $keywords are separated by space you can use in PHP explode, and then create construction with LIKE (val1 OR val2 OR...) and it should work.